# Azure storage trigger

Tags: azure, spring-boot, spring-cloud-function

I'm looking at the documentation for the `@BlobTrigger` and see that the content is being passed in as a byte array in the examples. Is it possible to have the spring `FileStorageResource` supplied? I can't find anything online indicating if this is possible

Comment: [azure-functions-java-library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-library) and [azure-webjobs-sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk) they all provide BlobTrigger. Is this what you want?

Comment: If a large file is added to blobstorage say 1GB, I don't want the content of the file handed to the function as a byte array. Can a spring Resource object be passed in, instead? The examples I've seen on MS website the signature is ```@BlobTrigger(name = "file",
               dataType = "binary",
               path = "myblob/{name}",
               connection = "MyStorageAccountAppSetting") byte[] content,
  @BindingName("name") String filename, final ExecutionContext context)```